# In ASP.NET, what to use to manage roles and permissions assigned to roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, permissions, role

I am working on a ASP.NET web application. I have this well known issue: each user can belong to one or several roles (admin, public users), and each role can have one or several permissions (can edit, can delete, can upload, etc.) and vice versa. I want to do smth like this: [http://demo.sitefinity.com/Sitefinity/Admin/Modules.aspx?route=GenericControlPanel.PermissionsView`1].

I found these options to implement this:

- using [NetSqlAzMan](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/) (but I am not sure it will work with our application, as our users are not stored in the same db than the application, and as we are using forms authentication)
- implementing my own classes which enable me to do: User.HasPermission / AddPermissionToUser / etc.
- using 2 role providers: one to manage the roles, one to manage permissions, knowing that these providers will be "linked", because of the m:n relationship between roles and permissions.
- I am using right now a custom role provider, so another option would be to add the methods to manage permissions to this provider.

I want also to cache roles and permissions for a given user. I think it will take me some time to do this on my own, so what do you suggest me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: First bullet - You can if you use DB Users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find a good packaged solution for a permissions module out there, I'd like to see it :)

Generally speaking, the built-in security providers stop after the "identification" and "authorization" part. Once identified, and authorized to access the application, more specific page or function level permissions are up to you to code and manage yourself.

The level of permissions you describe is actually quite an advanced one to implement. It mirrors access control lists (ACLs) in windows. While it seems fairly straight forward, it is actually quite difficult to code. Once you get into designing it you discover that you are having to implement a "deny" override permission, having to handle multi-level group permission merges, and then having to deal with "special" permissions and such. Then you run into the stuff like "does edit permissions imply view too, and what do I do if they don't have view but do have add"?

It can be a real mess.

Before you go implementing permissions at that level of complexity, I'd highly advise you to step back and see if you can flatten your permissions and role/group model a bit. Can you not just get away with having your roles BE the permissions? For example, a role for people who can edit, a role for people who can add, a role for people that can view... etc.

In most applications, you don't really need full ACL like granularity in the permissions system.

Once you've defined the appropriate level of permissions your application really needs, you are usually best off rolling a set of custom objects to manage those permissions. I have to say I've never considered using a second linked role provider as a permissions manager before... that's a kinda brilliant idea actually. But I'd still advise against it. The role provider wasn't designed for what you are trying to do and you'd likely have to extend and override the default behavior so much that it would be simpler and more maintainable just to have used a custom implementation from the ground up.

Comment: I have only glanced at the applicaiton's documentation and I like the idea. The big problem for me is that it seems to be a very old product. I opened the newest release and the dates on most of the files are either 2004 or 2006. The documentation is excellent, but never talks about newer platforms. It talks about server 2003, .NET 2.0, and SQL 2000. So my big concern would be that development on the product is dead. On the up-side though, the newest release is from this year even thought the files aren't new, so maybe it isn't dead or is about to be revived.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comments. I ended up doing my own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tool that combines authentication + permissions and roles + logging and auditing
http://visual-guard.com/

Authentication can be Windows, in this case it implements single sign-on
or a user name/password combination

2 consoles are available to manage users and permissions
- One is more developer-oriented and provides a wizard to define permission without coding (for .Net), deployment and versioning features.
- The other one is web based, non tech user adminitrators oriented, and focuses on user accounts, groups and mapping them to roles.

Permissions can be extremely fine grained with some kind of conditions (this form is visible to the role "doctors" from 8am to 11 am because it is related to medicines that have to be given only in the morning)

It was originally only .Net oriented, and now they support other technologies like Java, Delphi C++, basically any technology able to call web services.